# How to load lodash/fp in the browser?

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash/fp in a library written for the browser. I'm using Webpack for packaging my library.

In my code, I currently load lodash/fp as follow (ES2015-style. I transpile it using Babel):

```
import fp from "lodash/fp";
```

At runtime, from Chrome's debugger, I can notice the presence of the "standard" `_` object at the top level, with all the usual, non curried methods. However the `fp` object is not there and I can't access the fp-style methods.

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to produce a global import

```
import fp from "lodash/fp";
window.fp = fp;
```